# An inequality about borel measures in a proof

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

I'm having trouble with the inequality in the proof of the following claim:

> Let $E$ be a locally-compact separable metric space and let $\{\mu_n\}$ weak-* converge to $\mu$. If $\{|\mu_n|\}$ locally weak-* converges to $\lambda$ then $\lambda \geq |\mu|$

The proof begins:

> Let $A \subset E$ be a relatively compact open set, define:
>   $$A_t := \{x \in A | \text{dist}(x,\partial A) > t\}$$
>   and let $u \in C_c(A)$ be such that $\chi_{A_t} \leq u \leq \chi_A$. Then by Corollary 1.13 we have:
>   $$|\mu|(A_t) \leq \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} |\mu_n|(A_t) \quad (*)$$

Corollary 1.13 reads:

> Let $\mu:\mathcal{B}(E) \rightarrow [0,\infty]$ and $B \in \mathcal{B}(E)$. Then $$\mu(B) = \sup \{\mu(C)|C \subset B, C \text{ closed}\}$$ provided $\mu$ is $\sigma$ finite. Further: $$\mu(B) = \inf \{\mu(A)|A \supset B, A \text{ open}\}$$ holds if $E$ is a countable union of open sets, each of finite measure.

I'm confused about how they are obtaining the inequality. Are they even using the corollary? (they may not be, there are more steps in the proof -- but I didn't include them because it appeared to not be used in those steps).

Comment: How do $\mu_n$ relate to $\mu$?

Comment: Good question -- this is a multipart statement and I had failed to add this information. $\{\mu_n\}$ weak-* converges to $\mu$. (More is added above)

Comment: I also misstated the converging measures originally -- it should have been their absolute values converging to lambda. The first box is correct now (hopefully).

Comment: It does look like a mistake.. Maybe they meant another corollary.

Comment: Is there a way to get that inequality anyway?